# Math Symbol for Corresponds (Better definition of smash)

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I'm using

```
\overset{\smallfrown}{=}
```

to make the math symbol for corresponds. Is there a better definition for this symbol? If not how do I properly smash what I've defined? I tried

```
\smash{\overset{\smallfrown}{=}}
```

but it didn't come out right.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

I have always used:

```
\mathrel{\widehat{=}}
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Probably `\mathrel{\widehat{=}}`

Comment: Oh, you're right, forgot about that - added it. Vajra might accept the answer if it solves the problem, so that the question won't be listed as unanswered.